# Mediawiki note issue

Tags: mediawiki

I use mediawiki (1.28.2) and I can not make notes.
Here is the result I get with a preview.

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMSwo.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `{{note|Foo}}` has the effect of expanding the `note` template with the positional argument `Foo`. The result you are getting is because the `note` template doesn't exist in your MediaWiki installation.

The note template is located at the page `Template:Note` (or `Template:note` if you have set the first character of page names to be case-sensitive). If this page doesn't exist, then `{{note|Foo}}` will create the red link that you saw. If you create it with some content, then `{{note|Foo}}` will display the content that you added. For example, if you add the content `Hello, world!` then `{{note|Foo}}` will show "Hello, world!", and if you add the content `Hello, {{{1}}}!` then `{{note|Foo}}` will show "Hello, Foo!"

### Importing templates

It looks like you are expecting the `note` template to display an actual note. To do this, you need special syntax inside the template. Probably the quickest way to make it work is to import the template from the wiki that made the template that you want. However, this requires that you copy all of the other templates that that template uses, and install all the MediaWiki extensions that that template uses.

For example, if you want the [French Wikipedia's note template](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod%C3%A8le:Note), you need to copy the [Lire en ligne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod%C3%A8le:Lire_en_ligne) template and the [Correction syntaxique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Correction_syntaxique) module, and you need to install the [Cite](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cite) and [Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto) extensions. (If you remove everything after `{{#invoke:` from the note template, then you can get away without installing Scribunto or copying the Correction syntaxique module, which I would recommend, because installing Scribunto is a pain.)

You can also use `Special:Export` and `Special:Import` to make the copying process easier. Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/how-to-add-wikipedia-mbox-templates-to-your-own-mediawiki/) for some tips.

### Cite extension

Alternatively, instead of importing templates, you can just install the [Cite extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cite) and use its syntax natively. Here's an example from the Cite documentation:

```
According to scientists, the Sun is pretty big.<ref>E. Miller, ''The Sun''
(New York: Academic Press, 2005), 23-5.</ref> In fact, it is very
big.<ref group="footnotes"> Take their word for it. Don't look directly
at the sun!</ref>

==Notes==
<references group="footnotes" />

==References==
<references />
```

Here, the "Take their word for it" text will appear as a note, without the need for any templates.